# Sinatra and Chartkick Example

Tags: sinatra, chartkick

I am quite new to Ruby as web platform and learn best by adapting and expanding examples. I like Sinatra and want to use it and Chartkick to display charts. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting even the most trivial example running and there seems to be a dearth of full examples (lots of 'one liners'). Here's what I have:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'chartkick'

get '/' do
'<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
 <%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>'
end
```

So what devastatingly simple thing am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT, my solution based on accepted answer:**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'chartkick'

template :layout do
<<LAYOUT
<html>
<head>
<title>Sinatra ERB Chartkick Test</title>
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="chartkick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
LAYOUT
end

template :index do
<<INDEX
<center>
<h1>#{Time.now.inspect}</h1>
<p>
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5, "Hockey" => 2}) %>
</p>
</center>
INDEX
end

get '/' do
    erb :index
end
```

Additionally, for the sake of newbies (like me), I put the *chartkick.js* file in the *public* folder. Also added Hockey just to make sure it wasn't magically defaulting to some canned example. And who doesn't like hockey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the section of the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Inline%20Templates) you need to finish this example. If you don't want to make the views separate files, then either use inline templates, e.g.

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end

__END__

@@ layout
<html><body>
  <%= yield %>
</html></body>

@@ index
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
```

or named templates:

```
template :layout do
  <<LAYOUT
<html><body>
  <%= yield %>
</html></body>
LAYOUT
end

template :index do
  <<INDEX
    <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
    <%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
INDEX
end

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

I've used [heredocs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents) for convenience here, just be careful of the formatting.